# Limit parallel processes in CherryPy?

Tags: cherrypy, beagleboneblack

I have a CherryPy server running on a BeagleBone Black. Server generates a simple webpage and does local SPI reads / writes (hardware interface). The application is going to be used on a local network with 1-2 clients at a time.
I need to prevent a CherryPy class function being called twice, two or more instances before it completes.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It is general synchronization question, though *CherryPy* side has a subtlety. *CherryPy* is a threaded-server so it is sufficient to have an application level lock, e.g. `threading.Lock`.

The subtlety is that you can't see the *run-or-fail* behaviour from within a single browser because of pipelining, [Keep-Alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) or caching. Which one it is is hard to guess as the behaviour varies in Chromium and Firefox. As far as I can see *CherryPy* will try to serialize processing of request coming from single *TCP* connection, which effectively results in subsequent requests waiting for active request in a queue. With some trial-and-error I've found that adding cache-prevention token leads to the desired behaviour (even though Chromium still sends `Connection: keep-alive` for XHR where Firefox does not).

If *run-or-fail* in single browser isn't important to you you can safely ignore the previous paragraph and *JavaScript* code in the following example.

### Update

The cause of request serialisation coming from one browser to the same URL doesn't lie in server-side. It's an implementation detail of a browser cache ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30595857/2072035)). Though, the solution of adding random query string parameter, `nc`, is correct.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import threading
import time

import cherrypy


config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8
  }
}


class App:

  lock = threading.Lock()


  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    return '''<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
        <title>Lock demo</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qooxdoo/3.5.1/q.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
          function runTask(wait)
          {
            var url = (wait ? '/runOrWait' : '/runOrFail') + '?nc=' + Date.now();
            var xhr = q.io.xhr(url);
            xhr.on('loadend', function(xhr) 
            {
              if(xhr.status == 200)
              {
                console.log('success', xhr.responseText)
              }
              else if(xhr.status == 503)
              {
                console.log('busy');
              }
            });
            xhr.send();
          }

          q.ready(function()
          {
            q('p a').on('click', function(event)
            {
              event.preventDefault();

              var wait = parseInt(q(event.getTarget()).getData('wait'));
              runTask(wait);
            });
          });
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p><a href='#' data-wait='0'>Run or fail</a></p>
        <p><a href='#' data-wait='1'>Run or wait</a></p>
      </body>
      </html>
    '''

  def calculate(self):
    time.sleep(8)
    return 'Long task result'

  @cherrypy.expose
  def runOrWait(self, **kwargs):
    self.lock.acquire()
    try:
      return self.calculate()
    finally:
      self.lock.release()

  @cherrypy.expose
  def runOrFail(self, **kwargs):
    locked = self.lock.acquire(False)
    if not locked:
      raise cherrypy.HTTPError(503, 'Task is already running')
    else:
      try:
        return self.calculate()
      finally:
        self.lock.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

Answer (score 0):

As saaj commented, a simple threading.Lock() will prevent the handler from being run at the same time by another client. I might also add, [using cherrypy.session.acquire_lock()](http://blog.schmichael.com/2007/09/20/session-locking-and-performance-in-cherrypy/) will prevent the same client from the running two handlers simultaneously.

Refreshing article on Python locks and stuff: http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm

Although I would make saaj's solution much simpler by using a "with" statement in Python, to hide all those fancy lock acquisitions/releases and try/except block.

```
lock = threading.Lock()

@cherrypy.expose
def index(self):
    with lock:
        # do stuff in the handler.
        # this code will only be run by one client at a time
        return '<html></html>'
```